# Port number getting stripped out of URL

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I have an django based website that's presented through gunicorn with nginx as reverse proxy. It's on port 81.The relevant portion of the configuration file looks like this:

```
upstream elearning_server {
    server localhost:8000;
}

server {
    listen          81;
......
```

If you go to:

```
http://webaddress:81
```

the first time after you log in, it removes the port number and fails to connect to the website. If you then put the port number back into the url it works fine.

Has anyone got any suggestions of what I can try to fix this problem.

Comment: The problem is your redirect URL doesn't have the port, so it redirects to the login page without the port number.

Comment: @Burhan Khalid Can you please tell me what redirect URL is and how to put port number in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is that your web server, as part of the login process is 'redirecting' your browser to a different web address. The problem is that the web address your browser is being redirected to doesn't exist, because it is being redirected to the wrong web address. When you modify the web address, you are correcting this error.

Obviously the solution is to correct this problem in the code, so you are sent straight to the correct web address without you needing to correct this.

The solution depends on your code. It is worth looking at it with the following in mind.

Is there something like:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('http://website/dir/')
```

in your code somewhere? This would need to be altered to include the port number, i.e

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('http://website:81/dir/')
```

Or, even better,

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('/dir/')
```

(This will mean that it won't matter what port the server is on, because the redirect is 'relative'. This would be the usual way to code this sort of thing.)

If a quick perusal of the source doesn't cast any light, I would suggest that the next step would be to look in the access logs (and maybe error logs) from the web server, and look for '3xx' type messages, probably '301' and '302' messages, and this may give you some clue as to what is happening, and where in the code.

Comment: A portion of access log:
- - 10.6.192.17 - [23/Jun/2014:00:21:05 +0530]  "GET /accounts/login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2839 "http://website:81/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0".|||

user1 - 10.6.192.17 - [23/Jun/2014:00:21:11 +0530]  "POST /accounts/login/ HTTP/1.1" 302 5 "http://website:81/accounts/login/" "Mozilla/5.|||

user1 - 10.6.192.17 - [23/Jun/2014:00:24:58 +0530]  "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0".|||

Comment: The code contains this:(views.py) if request.user.is_authenticated(): return redirect(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL) and in the file settings.py: LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/courseware/'

Comment: Is the address "website:81/accounts/login/" which occurs in the logs the correct one that you want to reach? Am I correct in thinking that the log files above comes up there without manual intervention, i.e., you didn't have to change the web address manually to get these entries?

Comment: Yeah, These logs are without manual intervention. And yes the address is correct. The problem seems to be with the third log entry. I followed your suggestion in the answer and changed the redirect URL to absolute. It worked.

Comment: That is great that it worked. That said, it is not a fantastic solution. If you ever move the application to another web address it will (obviously) break again. I'd say there might be some issue with the reverse proxy. Hard to diagnose that from here, and I really don't know that much about nginx and unicorn